# Translation of active record models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, devise, rails-i18n

I set the default_locale of my rails app to french: `config.i18n.default_locale = :fr`

Then I installed devise gem. And applied `devise` to the model `Membre`.

new.html.erb:

```
<h2><%= t('login') %></h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "email" %>
  </div>
```

fr.yml

```
fr:
  login: "S'indentifer"
  
  activerecord:
    models:
      Membre:
    attributes:
      Membre:
        email: "e-mail"
        password: "mot de passe"
```

Login gets translated, so the i18n configuration is ok.
but email and password remain in English.

Comment: can you share the en.yml file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the downcase model name like below and check the rails guide for more details - https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models

```
fr:
  login: "S'indentifer"
  
  activerecord:
    models:
      membre:
    attributes:
      membre:
        email: "e-mail"
        password: "mot de passe"
```